# About hash function used in hashmap (khash)?

Tags: c, hashmap, hashtable

I see the following hash functions. But I don't know why they are defined in that way. Does anybody know where I can find explanations for these hash functions? Thanks.

https://github.com/attractivechaos/klib/blob/master/khash.h#L368

```
#define kh_int64_hash_func(key) (khint32_t)((key)>>33^(key)^(key)<<11)

static kh_inline khint_t __ac_X31_hash_string(const char *s)
{
    khint_t h = (khint_t)*s;
    if (h) for (++s ; *s; ++s) h = (h << 5) - h + (khint_t)*s;
    return h;
}
static kh_inline khint_t __ac_Wang_hash(khint_t key)
{
    key += ~(key << 15);
    key ^=  (key >> 10);
    key +=  (key << 3);
    key ^=  (key >> 6);
    key += ~(key << 11);
    key ^=  (key >> 16);
    return key;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This hash function seems to have been originally published by Thomas Wang. The original website is no longer available, but you can find it on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20071223173210/http://www.concentric.net/%7ETtwang/tech/inthash.htm). There is also a [reformatted version of the same text](https://gist.github.com/badboy/6267743) on gist.github.com which I've seen linked from [another hashtable library](https://github.com/mattiasgustavsson/libs/blob/a64e6e6f06b7b8392cec5614280f70411282508c/hashtable.h#L436). The comments also link this [avalanche analysis on Wang's function](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/integer.html) which you might find interesting.